# A different solution for checking convergence of $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\dots+\frac{1}{(2n)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, summation

> Analyse the convergence of
> $$a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\dots+\frac{1}{(2n)^2}$$
> and find the point of convergence if it does converge.

I proved that it converges to $0$ noting that
$$\frac{1}{n^2} \le a_n \le (n+1)\times \frac{1}{n^2}$$
and using Sandwich Theorem.

But I was following a book by Arihant which gives the following solution (and I am quoting it without changing any notations)

> Define $a_n=\frac n{(n+n)^2}$ so that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=0$. Now, use Cauchy's Theorem to get
> $$0=\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{a_1+\dots a_n}n\right)=\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\dots \frac 1{(2n)^2}\right)$$
> and hence the result follows.

I believe this solution is absolutely rubbish (although it would be good to have a check). But, I do like the idea and the approach. Can this approach (with necessary modifications) be used to solve these kind of limits?

Comment: I don't get how the following argument works- $$\left(\frac{a_1+\dots a_n}n\right)=\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\dots \frac 1{(2n)^2}\right)$$

Comment: @SayanDutta same question here

Comment: It seems to be convergent. $(n+k)^2> (n+k), k=0,\cdots n$. So $\sum_0^n\frac{1}{(n+k)^2}<\sum_0^n\frac{1}{(n+k)}$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring yes, you are right, I'll fix that!

Answer (score 4):

just for the fun of it :-)
\begin{align}
0\leq a_n &= \sum_{j=0}^{n}\frac{1}{(n+j)^2} \\
&\leq \sum_{j=0}^{n}\frac{1}{(n+j)n}\\
& = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{j=0}^{n}\frac{1}{1+\frac jn}\\
& = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac1n\times\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x}\\
& = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac1n \times \ln2\\
& = 0
\end{align}

Comment: I also thought about it (+1)... I am just concerned a little about its rigour...

Comment: @Nobody: So you should be! That $\lim$ appears out of nowhere.

Comment: @Nobody Thanks: the integral is the limit of the Riemann sum

Answer (score 4):

Compute an upper bound
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac1{k^2}
&\le\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac1{(k-1)k}\tag{1a}\\
&=\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\left(\frac1{k-1}-\frac1k\right)\tag{1b}\\
&=\frac1{n-1}-\frac1{2n}\tag{1c}\\
&=\frac{n+1}{2n(n-1)}\tag{1d}\\
&\le\frac1{2n-4}\tag{1e}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a):}$ $\frac1{k^2}\le\frac1{(k-1)k}$
$\text{(1b):}$ partial fractions
$\text{(1c):}$ telescoping series
$\text{(1d):}$ combine fractions
$\text{(1e):}$ cross multiply: $2n^2-2n-4\le2n^2-2n$

Although $0$ is a sufficient lower bound, we can compute a better lower bound
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac1{k^2}
&\ge\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac1{k(k+1)}\tag{2a}\\
&=\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}\right)\tag{2b}\\
&=\frac1n-\frac1{2n+1}\tag{2c}\\
&=\frac{n+1}{n(2n+1)}\tag{2d}\\
&\ge\frac1{2n}\tag{2e}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a):}$ $\frac1{k^2}\ge\frac1{k(k+1)}$
$\text{(2b):}$ partial fractions
$\text{(2c):}$ telescoping series
$\text{(2d):}$ combine fractions
$\text{(2e):}$ cross multiply: $2n^2+2n\ge2n^2+n$

Therefore,
$$
\frac1{2n}\le\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac1{k^2}\le\frac1{2n-4}\tag3
$$
and we can apply the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

---

Of course, if we know that the series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}$ converges, then the desired result follows from the fact that the partial sums of a convergent series are a [Cauchy sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence).

Comment: If we use the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula, we get the asymptotic expansion $$\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac1{k^2}=\frac1{2n}+\frac5{8n^2}+\frac7{48n^3}-\frac{31}{960n^5}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^7}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

As it's given that, $a_{n}=\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+...\frac{1}{(2n)^2}$

To make it more understandable, we can write $a_{n'}$ instead of $a_{n}$ where $n'=0,1,....n$

So, we can write $a_{n'}$ as,

$a_{n'}=\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+...\frac{1}{(2n)^2}=\sum_{n'=0}^{n}\frac{1}{(n+n')^2}$

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n'}$=$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\sum_{n'=0}^{n}\frac{1}{(n+n')^2}$)

From here, we can easily interpret that,

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\sum_{n'=0}^{n}\frac{1}{(n+n')^2}$)=0

So, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n'}$=0.

Comment: I really don't understand this solution, can you please elaborate...

Comment: I have edited it now to make it more clear...At the end, you can use cauchy sequence (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence) to evaluate the limit